# Atualizar um subdocumento do mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Eu tenho um array de objetos:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: String,
    servers: Array
});
```

No final, acaba ficando parecido com isso:

```
servers: [
    0: {
        sv_id: '123456789',
        users: [
            colors: [
                {
                    name: 'Vermelho',
                    rgb: '255,0,0',
                    unlocked: false
                },{
                    name: 'Verde',
                    rgb: '0,255,0',
                    unlocked: false // unlocked significa se o usuário tem a cor desbloqueada, ou seja, se ele pode usar essa cor 
                },
            ]
        ] 
    },
    1: {
        sv_id: '123456789',
        users: [
            colors: [
                {
                    name: 'Vermelho',
                    rgb: '255,0,0',
                    unlocked: true
                },{
                    name: 'Verde',
                    rgb: '0,255,0',
                    unlocked: false
                },
            ]
        ] 
    },
]
```

O que eu estou tentando fazer é arranjar uma maneira de, por meio de um comando, alterar a propriedade `unlocked` de uma cor especifica.

EX: Fazer isso:

```
{
    name: 'Vermelho',
    rgb: '255,0,0',
    unlocked: false
},
```

...virar isso:

```
{
    name: 'Vermelho',
    rgb: '255,0,0',
    unlocked: true
},
```

Mas, mesmo tentando tudo que achei, nada funcionou. Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão de como resolver isso, iria me ajudar muito! Obrigado.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a opção `arrayFilters` para definir um identificador para uma sub-query dentro dos seus *arrays*, e então utilizar esse identificador como índice no seu update.

A documentação completa está [no site do MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), mas para facilitar a visualização aqui está um exemplo com o seu modelo:

```
User.updateOne(
  { "user_id": "13579" },
  { "servers.$[server].users.$[].colors.$[color].unlocked": true },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "server.sv_id": "123456789" },
      { "color.name": "Vermelho" }
    ]
  }
)
```

Veja que eu defini o identificador `sever` para o *array* `servers`, onde a sub-query é `sv_id` == "123456789".

Também defini o identificador `color` para o *array* `colors`, onde a sub-query é `name` == "Vermelho".

Porém não precisei definir um identificador para `users`, o que significa que o update será feito em todos os users, sem nenhum condicional.

[Aqui tem um link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sRwtpyk234G) desse exemplo rodando no Mongo Playground para interação.

Comment: Graças a sua resposta, consegui fazer. Acabou que o problema não era só um, mas vários, indo desde a estrutura do schema, até a utilização de métodos errados. Muito obrigado, marquei sua respostas como correta!